# Java special chars replace

Tags: java, string, email, encoding

I have a text:
"
Csuklási roham gyötörheti a svédeket, annyit emlegetik mostanság ismét a svéd modellt Magyarországon."

In that original text there are no line breaks at all.

When I email this text (with gmail), I get it encoded as the following:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Csukl=E1si roham gy=F6t=F6rheti a sv=E9deket, annyit emlegetik mostans=E1g =
ism=E9t a
sv=E9d modellt Magyarorsz=E1gon.
```

In HTML:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


<span class=3D"Apple-style-span" style=3D"font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, = sans-serif; font-size: 15px; ">Csukl=E1si roham gy=F6t=F6rheti a sv=E9deket= , annyit emlegetik mostans=E1g ism=E9t a sv=E9d modellt Magyarorsz=E1gon.
```

....

When I try to parse the email body as text/plain, I cannot get rid of the = sign in "mostans=E1g =
    ism=E9t" between the two words. Note that the same character is missing from the HTML encoded message. I don't have any idea what that special character might be, but I need to eliminate it to get back the original text.

I tried to replace '\n' but it's not that one, if I hit 'Enter' in the text, I can correctly replace it to whatever character I want it to. I also tried '\r', and '\t'.

So the question is, what am I missing? Where does that special character come from? Is it because of the charser and/or the transfer encoding? If so, what do I have to do to solve the problem and get the original text back.

Any help would be welcome.

Cheers,
Balázs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [MimeUtility](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html).Here is an example.

```
public class Mime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException,
            IOException {
        InputStream stringStream = new FileInputStream("mime");
        InputStream output = MimeUtility.decode(stringStream,
                "quoted-printable");
        System.out.println(convertStreamToString(output));
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the Reader.read(char[]
         * buffer) method. We iterate until the Reader return -1 which means
         * there's no more data to read. We use the StringWriter class to
         * produce the string.
         */
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "ISO8859_1"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The file *'mime'* contains encoded text:

```
Csukl=E1si roham gy=F6t=F6rheti a sv=E9deket, annyit emlegetik mostans=E1g =
ism=E9t a
sv=E9d modellt Magyarorsz=E1gon.
```

**UPDATE:**

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library :

```
    InputSupplier<InputStream> supplier = new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("mime");
            InputStream decodedStream=null;
            try {
                decodedStream = MimeUtility.decode(inStream,
                "quoted-printable");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return decodedStream;
        }
    };
    InputSupplier<InputStreamReader> result = CharStreams
    .newReaderSupplier(supplier, Charsets.ISO_8859_1);
    String ans = CharStreams.toString(result);
    System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: @Balázs Mária Németh:yes it is eliminated but i see an extra newline which was not there in the original text.Maybe it like what jarnbjo says that the "quoted-printable" forbids encoded lines to exceed a length of 76 characters.

Comment: @Balázs Mária Németh:Read about the [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).This will help you understand about the encoding.

Comment: it works. convertStreamToString was a bit confusing, since InputStream output = MimeUtility.decode(stringStream,
                "quoted-printable"); was the key but the vast majority of your answer was that method mentioned above :)

Comment: @Balázs Mária Németh: Do you also get an extra new-line ?

Comment: I was wrong, I can see those extra lines, yes! So that means I have both \n and \r\n, and the latter being the real one?

Comment: @Emil: This isn't quite the correct way to use `InputSupplier`. An `InputSupplier` should return a new `InputStream` or `Reader` or whatever each time its `getInput()` method is called. Here, your `InputSupplier` should probably take an `InputSupplier<? extends InputStream>` in its constructor. In `getInput()`, it should call `getInput()` on that supplier, then wrap that stream using `MimeUtility.decode` and return the result. Then you could use that with `Files.newInputStreamSupplier(File)`.

Comment: @ColinD:I have corrected it.But i'm not quite sure if this is what you meant in the above comment.Please check it if it's not right please edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The transfer encoding "quoted-printable" forbids encoded lines to exceed a length of 76 characters. If the text to be encoded contains longer text lines, a "soft line break" has to be inserted, which is indicated by a single '=' as the last character of an encoded line. It means that the following line break is only inserted to fulfill the 76 character restriction and that the following line break should be removed when decoding the transfer encoding.

Comment: To add to this, the line break is likely "\r\n", not just "\r" or "\n".

Comment: It's not only likely, but obligatory. Only CRLF (\r\n) line breaks are allowed in quoted-printable.